# Bitbucket Markdown - Add a Table to a Numbered List Item

Tags: bitbucket, markdown

I wish to add a table to a numbered list in bitbucket markdown.

Something like this:

```
1. Define the following role for the user:     

    |Role            |Description           |                                          
    |---             |---                   |                                              
    |**UserRole**    |The role is blah-blah |

2. Etc
```

I tried indenting by 4 spaces and 8 spaces. Neither shows the table as it should, but the 8 spacing at least shows the table as a pre-formatted table. What can be done to present the table as a proper table?

Answer (score 2):

I solved distorted table rendering in a numbered list in Bitbucket by removing outside (most left and most right) vertical bars for all rows. The appearance of the table stayed unchanged.

Following your example:

```
1. Define the following role for the user:  

    Role            |Description                                                     
    ---             |---                                                                 
    **UserRole**    |The role is blah-blah 

2. Etc
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  If your page is publicly visible, please add a link

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have either encountered a bug or Bitbucket has intentionally disallowed such behavior. Unfortunately, Bitbucket's documentation regarding [table](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html#Markdownsyntaxguide-Tables) support is extremely sparse. It consists solely of the following example:

> ```
> | Day     | Meal    | Price |
> | --------|---------|-------|
> | Monday  | pasta   | $6    |
> | Tuesday | chicken | $8    |
> ```

Rumor has it that Bitbucket uses Python-Markdown as their Markdown parser (full discloser: I am the developer of Python-Markdown). However, I have never seen any official confirmation of that. And which table extension they use is even less clear. As it happens, the table extension that comes with Python-Markdown parses your example just fine, which suggests they are using some custom extension.

I would suggest filing a bug report with Bitbucket.

Comment: Thanks Waylan. I will raise.